# How do I change the attributes of an RMWC Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-components-web

I have an RMWC Button element, and I want to change the `icon` attribute when an onClick event is fired.

```
<Button outlined icon={<CircularProgress />}
    onClick={(e)=> {
        // e.currentTarget.icon = '';
        // console.log(e.currentTarget.icon) 
        // ??? :V
}} 
>Export</Button>
```

More specifically, I'm trying to make the Button stop loading when the button is clicked :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do with `useState` update method

```
const [load,setLoad] =  useState(true);

<Button outlined icon={load ? <CircularProgress />:<SomeOtherIcon/>}
    onClick={(e)=> setLoad(false)} >Export</Button>
```